# Preg replace with accent letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, special-characters

I am trying to insert a break after a name in a string. But, the name can have characters like é

```
$string = 'Test string';
$name = 'Tést';

$replacement = '$0<br />$1';
return preg_replace("/^$name/i", $replacement, $string);
```

I would like this to return:

```
Test<br /> string
```

Tést could also be something like: Héllo, byé or nùl
This should be possible right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you do not really control the content of `$name` you could be in for a surprise when it shows up with regexp characters. Think `.`, `|`, etc. You get the idea. Depending on what you are trying to achieve this may even become a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something like this to collate accents:

```
$collate = [
    "À-Æ" => "A", "à-æ" => "a", "Ç"   => "C", "ç"   => "c",
    "È-Ë" => "E", "è-ë" => "e", "Ì-Ï" => "I", "ì-ï" => "i",
    "Ñ"   => "N", "ñ"   => "n", "Ò-Ø" => "O", "ò-ø" => "o",
    "ß"   => "s", "Ù-Ü" => "U", "ù-ü" => "u", "Ý"   => "Y", "ý" => "y"
];

$string = "Test string";
$name = "Tést";

foreach($collate as $from => $to) {
    $name = preg_replace("/[".$from."]/", $to, $name);
}
// echo $name; => "Test"

return preg_replace("/^".$name."/", "$0<br />", $string);
// result: "Test<br /> string"
```

Comment: Sorry for the repeated edit tweaking, I keep on reading your question slightly differently each time XD